# How to use filter in dynamically in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the raw of line of logs file about 1TB. As below.

```
Test X1 SET WARN CATALOG MAP1,MAP2
INFO X2 SET WARN CATALOG MAPX,MAP2,MAP3
```

I read the logs file using spark scala scala and make the rdd of logs file.

I need to filter only those line which contains

```
1.SET 
2.INFO 
3. CATALOG
```

I write the filter like that

```
Val filterRdd = rdd.filter(f =>f.contains("SET")).filter(f => f.contains("INFO")).filter(f =>f.contains("CATALOG"))
```

can we do the same if these parameter are assign to list. and based on that we can filter dynamically not writing to much of line ; here in example i take only three restriction but in real it goes to upto 15 restriction keywords. can we do it dynamically.

Comment: Does the line have to contain all words or any of them?

Comment: yes must contain; can we also add "or" condition if any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this could work when you require all words to appear in a line:

```
val words = Seq("SET", "INFO", "CATALOG")
val filterRdd = rdd.filter(f => words.forall(w => f.contains(w)))
```

and if you want any:

```
val filterRdd = rdd.filter(f => words.exists(w => f.contains(w)))
```